# Changing an active low decoder to active high?

Tags: integrated-circuit, inverter, decoder

I apologize if my question sounds stupid, but I'm a novice and trying to explore all of my options. I currently have a 4/16 decoder, but I did not realize it was active-low and what I really need is an active-high decoder. How might I go about fixing this without putting an inverter on every output? Thanks!

(datasheet: https://datasheet.octopart.com/NTE74HC154-NTE-Electronics-datasheet-22129262.pdf)

Comment: I'm considering just buying a 16-gate inverter if that exists

Comment: The datasheet should have explained that. Looks like 3 7404s, or modify the downstream logic to require active-low.

Comment: Since TTL “0” was low impedance , active state delays for fall time were lower, this TTL was designed that way but not true for CMOS yet 74HC series must be compatible. You must learn what is the best solution, there are many, as long as it works. Getting it to fit is your problem which has many solutions too.

Comment: You could use two off 74HCT240 to get 16 inverters.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I was in a bit of a rush and this was the only decoder available, so I didn't check the datasheet when I got it (should have). Downstream is just some leds with a pull-down resistor, so I can't think of a way to modify this to also be active low. Any ideas? (Might just go with 7404s)

Comment: Is that all? Run the LEDs with pull UP resistors to +V. That's how it was always done in the TTL (good at pulling low) days.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Would that look something like this?     (4/16 decoder output pin)------(resistor to V+)-------(led)

Comment: @CalebWhittington yes, although it's more traditional to put the resistor on the VCC side of the LED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just invert the logic of the downstream circuitry.

To drive a LED, do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMVXrK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(BUF1 is just any of your decoder's output pins) The resistor and LED can be interchanged.
That's the way TTL circuitry (good at pulling low) was always used.